# записи с кастомным типом статуса не видны в админке при сохранении, как их вывести?

Tags: wordpress

```
   function my_custom_status_creation(){
            register_post_status( 'approved', array(
                'label'                     => _x( 'Песочница', 'post' ),
                'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Песочница <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Песочница <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
                'public'                    => false,
                'exclude_from_search'       => true,
                'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
                'show_in_admin_status_list' => true
            ));
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_status_creation' );
    
        function my_custom_status_add_in_quick_edit() {
            echo "<script>
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {
                jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( '<option value=\"sandbox\">Песочница</option>' );      
            }); 
            </script>";
        }
        add_action('admin_footer-edit.php','my_custom_status_add_in_quick_edit');
        function my_custom_status_add_in_post_page() {
            echo "<script>
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {        
                jQuery( 'select[name=\"post_status\"]' ).append( '<option value=\"sandbox\">Песочница</option>' );
            });
            </script>";
        }
        add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'my_custom_status_add_in_post_page');
        add_action('admin_footer-post-new.php', 'my_custom_status_add_in_post_page');
        
     

   

    // Эта функция делает все записи Пользователя со статусом sandbox/*
 

 

      add_action( 'save_post', 'set_sandbox' );
        function set_sandbox( $post_id ){
         /* if (get_user_meta(get_post($post_id)->post_author, 'account_key', 1) == 'Пользователь'){
        }*/
                // Получим реальный ID поста, если это ревизия
                  if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
                      $post_id = $parent_id;
                // Удаляем хук, чтобы не было зацикливания
                remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_sandbox' );
        
                // обновляем запись. В это время срабатывает событие save_post
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'sandbox' ) );
        
                // Ставим хук обратно
                add_action( 'save_post', 'set_sandbox' );
            
        }
```

Comment: это не тип записи. это статус поста

Comment: да,но эти записи существуют ,но в админке их нету